# Mongo remove() error when passing doc _id as string using ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

```
coll.remove(params[:id])
```

I pass the ID string through the URL `?id=546a691d7b76eb0909000001`

I receive the following error on the line of code:

```
Database command 'delete' failed: wrong type for 'q' field, expected object, found q: "546a691d7b76eb0909000001"
```

Do I need to convert the string to an ObjectID and if so how?

Comment: Convert to BSON::ObjectId("546a691d7b76eb0909000001")  before calling coll.remove()

Comment: What driver are you using? [This](http://rubygems.org/gems/mongo)?

Comment: Yes I used "gem instal mongo"

Comment: I tried coll.remove(BSON::ObjectId(params[:id])) but this also failed with the same error

Comment: i tried: id= BSON::ObjectId.from_string(params[:id]) then
  coll.remove(id) but received the following similar error: Mongo::OperationFailure - Database command 'delete' failed: wrong type for 'q' field, expected object, found q: ObjectId('546a691d7b76eb0909000001')

Comment: I got it working:coll.remove( { "_id" => BSON::ObjectId.from_string(params[:id])})

Answer (score 1):

I got it working:

coll.remove( { "_id" => BSON::ObjectId.from_string(params[:id])})

I was missing the "_id" => and I needed to use BSON::ObjectId.from_string